# Write a incremental value in flash memory of MSP430 (Cold start Power on Count)

Tags: c, pointers, msp430

I'm trying to implement power on count.
It count up whenever product is powered on.
so I write this counting on the flash memory of MSP430F249;
I would like to make 2bytes for write value of counting
However, I could not write a value
like 00 01, 00 02, 00 03, 00 04, ....

```
    uint16_t *Flash_ptr;                          // Flash pointer

    Flash_ptr = (char *)0x1040;               // Initialize Flash pointer
    FCTL3 = FWKEY;                            // Clear Lock bit
    FCTL1 = FWKEY + ERASE;                    // Set Erase bit
    *Flash_ptr = 0;                           // Dummy write to erase Flash seg

    FCTL1 = FWKEY + WRT;                      // Set WRT bit for write operation

   
    Flash_ptr = 0x0001;                   // Write value to flash
    

    FCTL1 = FWKEY;                            // Clear WRT bit
    FCTL3 = FWKEY + LOCK;                     // Set LOCK bit
```

Comment: If you want to write 2-bytes to the address pointed to by `Flash_ptr`, shouldn't that by `*Flash_ptr = (uint16_t)1;`? That way you are updating the 2-bytes at address `0x1040`. Or why not declare `uint16_t *Flash_ptr;` to begin with?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Right. I changed a code and did test. but It looks like just 00000100001

Comment: That is strange. I don't have much experience with MSP430, but without looking at the data sheet, etc., are you sure you can write to `0x1040`? If you are getting `0x21` after storing `0x1` as a `uint16_t` at that address -- either it isn't writing 2-bytes, or your 2-bytes are being overwritten.  (also -- when you edit your question -- don't delete the original text, just **add** your edits below the original -- otherwise comments before your change will no longer make sense `:)`

Comment: Also recall what with embedded systems, memory addresses that are not specifically listed as being available to be written to may very well be used by the microcontroller in some other proprietary unpublished manner. The controller is free to do whatever it wants to addresses not specifically listed as being user writeable addresses. Something like that may also bite you unexpectedly.

Comment: Based on this spec: https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau144j/slau144j.pdf?ts=1595400375407&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FMSP430F249 you need to wait for *done* after writing to the flash before locking it back: `L2: BIT #BUSY, &FCTL3 ; Test BUSY` and `JNZ L2 ; Loop while busy`

Comment: Looks like you are attempting to write with the 256-byte "Information Memory" Flash. See [MSP430F249 data sheet - Table 12.](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/msp430f249) It will take more reading to determine if there is any limitation there. The memory range is from `0x10FF - 0x1000` so you are attempting to write to bytes `63`, `62` from the bottom of the range.

Comment: Looks like you need to comply with Section 7.2-7.3 of the User Guide you link. You are writing to `Section D` of the `"Information Memory"` section. Double check you are setting the bytes correctly to write instead of block-write and erase instead of mass-erase. Also check the requirement of code being in RAM if any CPU operation is taking place during the Flash programming.

Comment: @David C. Rankin Thanks for helping me. I solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Good for you. Learning C is quite a challenge. Learning a microcontroller at the same time takes every bit is as much effort as learning the basics of C. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with initiazation of flash memory

```
         // Initialize Flash memory
        uint16_t *Flash_ptr;                          // Flash pointer
        uint16_t power_on_count;
        uint16_t endian_swap;

        Flash_ptr = (uint16_t *)0x1040;               // Initialize Flash pointer

        // read power on count from flash memory and add 1
        while ((FCTL3 & BUSY) != 0);
        power_on_count = *Flash_ptr;
        power_on_count = power_on_count + 0x0001;
        endian_swap = power_on_count >> 8 | power_on_count <<8 ;
        g_stCold_start_cnt.cold_start_cnt = (uint16_t)endian_swap;

        // write an increased power on count on the flash memory
        FCTL3 = FWKEY;                            // Clear Lock bit
        FCTL1 = FWKEY + ERASE;                    // Set Erase bit
        *Flash_ptr = 0;                           // Dummy write to erase Flash seg

        FCTL1 = FWKEY + WRT;                      // Set WRT bit for write operation

        while ((FCTL3 & BUSY) != 0);

        if(power_on_count == 0xFF)
        {
            power_on_count = 0;
        }

         *Flash_ptr = power_on_count;                   // Write value to flash

        FCTL1 = FWKEY;                            // Clear WRT bit
        FCTL3 = FWKEY + LOCK;                     // Set LOCK bit
```